# Azure Blob Bindings with Azure Function (Python)

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I currently have a process of reading from sql, using pandas and pd.Excelwriter to format the data and email it out. I want my function to read from sql (no problem) and write to a blob, then from that blob (using SendGrid binding) attach that file from the blob and send it out.

My question is do I need both an in (attaching for email) and an out (archiving to the blob) binding for that blob? Additionally, is this the simplest way to do this? It's be nice to send it and write to the blob as two unconnected operations instead of sequentially.

It also appears that with the binding, I have to hard code the name of the file in the blob-path? That seems a little ridiculous, does anyone know a workaround, or perhaps I have misunderstood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> do I need both an in (attaching for email) and an out (archiving to
>   the blob) binding for that blob?

Firstly I don't think you could bind the blob in and out simultaneously if the not existed. If you have tried you will find it will return error. And I suppose you could send the mail directly with  the content from sql and write to blob, don't need to read content from blob again.

> I have to hard code the name of the file in the blob-path?

If you could accept guid or datetime blob name you could bind the path with `{rand-guid}` or `{DateTime}`(you could format the time).

I fyou could not accept this binding, you could pass the blob path from the trigger body with json data like below pic. If you use other like queue trigger, you also could pass the json data with the path value.

[image]

Comment: Thank you I will try this today. That didnt seem right having to hardcode the name.

Comment: I have an issue of : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage: Settings must be of the form "name=value"

Comment: Did you set `AzureWebJobsStorage` in the local.settings.json ?

Comment: @Robert Riley, any process?

Comment: Thank you, I had a mistake in the local.settings. Sorry for the delay.